# Unescape an escaped string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm running a loop to display characters of a specific Unicode escape sequence.

```
var es = '';

for (var i = 0; i <= 9999; i++) {
  if (i < 10) {
    es = '\\u000' + i;
  } else if (i < 100) {
    es = '\\u00' + i;
  } else {
    es = '\\u' + i;
  }
  console.log(es);
}
```

...however, it doesn't display the characters, just the sequence. Is there anyway in JavaScript to unescape the escaped sequence to force it show the character?

Comment: Note that your code doesn’t create correct escape sequences: it doesn’t zero-pad correctly and it uses decimal numbers instead of [the hexadecimal numbers that Unicode escapes require](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode). Use a library like [jsesc](https://mths.be/jsesc) if you ever need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you'll want to use `String.fromCharCode()`

```
var es = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 9999; ++i) {
  es = String.fromCharCode(i);
  // ...
}
```

The `\uNNNN` syntax only works with constant values inside the larger string constant.

*edit* — an important comment below points out that due to the problematic UTF-16 implementation of JavaScript strings, `.fromCharCode()` has problems with characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane. For that, the ES6 (ES2015) has `String.fromCodePoint()`, a similar function that *does* handle "astral" characters outside the 16-bit range. [More on that here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) and in the link in the comment.

Comment: Interesting, quick question. Why does fromCharCode('\u2665') return an empty string, while if I just console log the sequence I get ♥

Comment: The `fromCharCode()` function expects its argument to be a number. When it tries to convert `'\u2665'` to a number, it gets `NaN`, so you get an empty string back. Try `String.fromCharCode(parseInt("2665", 16))` instead.

Comment: What to do with values such as \uabc1 etc

Comment: @arniekoz `String.fromCharCode(parseInt("abc1", 16))`

Comment: Actually, you want `String.fromCodePoint`, which (unlike `String.fromCharCode`) [handles astral characters correctly](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#code-point-to-symbol).

Comment: @MathiasBynens ah yes, you're right; that's a good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling across this question (most likely my future self) looking to "unescape" a previously escaped [Javascript special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#using_special_characters_in_strings), here's a hacky way to do it:

```js
newString = JSON.stringify(string).slice(1,-1)
```

However this seems to only work for certain characters, like `\t`, `\n`, `\r`, `\f`, `\b`, `\\`, etc.

To explain myself better, in the case of tabs, this will convert a tab character back into literal/raw string that is `\t`.

Comment: Motivation for this answer: https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/issues/370